# Connecting data tables (data model), not joining them, in R, Python, Julia or

Tags: javascript, python, r, python-3.x, julia

Is there any equivalent way to connecting data like what we do in BI software (i.e., Power Bi or Tableau) and then Query from them?

To clarify:
We use explicit join in programming languages for example `new_table = inner_join(a,b, by = c)` so the new table is calculated and final, but in BI tools we introduce data model, you can see a model in the picture, it is not calculated now, then we perform multi tables query without any explicit join. The software itself decide how to retrieve data from the data model just in time.

[image]

```
HR_tables %>% group_by(DEPARTMENTS$department_name) %>% (sum(EMPLOYEES$salary))
```

Comment: I voted to close this question as it stands, as it too broad, and also unclear. It seems like you want to maybe join two or three tables, and then do a simple groupby and summing operation, which is certainly possible in python, r, julia, or most other languages that have some sort of dataframe-like object.

Comment: It seems pretty broad but I don't think it is unclear. All SQL databases support views using the `create view` statement and the languages in question can connect to such databases.

Comment: I have never seen such a capability in any of these languages. let it be open.

Comment: I vote to re-open this question. The author should edit it and explicitly state that he is asking about views for data frames. Note that Julia has the broadest support for non-materialized data from perhaps almost all programming languages. You have `@view`, there are `SparseArrays`, `BandedMatrices` etc. Hence talking about non-materialized data frames makes a perfect sense. BTW in `DataFrames.jl` you can decide not to materialize a copy of column by using `[!, :colname]` selector.

Comment: I am not familiar with BI. This sounds like a lazy data table, but where is the data actually stored? In a remote database? In files on your disk? In non-lazy data tables (in Julia and Python, it'd be a DataFrame)?

Comment: @BatWannaBe I understand that the question is about a lazy data frame. Like in Julia we have a lazy view of a matrix.

Answer (score 0):

The idea of a query optimizer being used with non-materialized views in a relational system such as a data warehouse generally doesn't have a direct corollary in any of these languages. You do see this sort of optimizer in action in systems like Mahout Samsara or Tensorflow.

Another analog to a traditional relational query optimizer can be found in Julia in the way that the optimizer can transform broadcast expressions. In many cases, unnecessary data allocation in such an expression can be cut to zero by transforming what appears to be a pipeline to an in-place progressive mutation.

You also see some analogous lazy evaluation in the [LazyArrays](https://github.com/JuliaArrays/LazyArrays.jl) system in Julia but, again, this is not oriented towards the relational join optimization that you described earlier.

Part of the lack of these systems in Julia and in Spark is the difference in focus. Non-materialized views and complex join optimization show up in systems where normalized forms are prevalent (aka relational systems). Normalized forms are very nice when you want to always see the latest updates so, say, a person's address. To a lesser extent, joins also become important when you have a central fact table which references dimensions as in a snowflake architecture (again, reference to up-to-date information like addresses and phone numbers is considered a benefit.

In many more modern systems, however, there is a much larger focus on dataflow designs and on preserving the data as it originally was presented. Most joins consist of very large datasets or even realtime data streams against relatively small dimension tables, or they are very large datasets against very large datasets. Joins are typically minimized in these systems because of an emphasis on denormalized data as a partial consequence of geographically distributed systems and partially a consequence of a focus on preserving data as it originally appeared rather than keeping it entirely up to date. The optimization of the trivial joins that show up in these systems is pretty simple and you don't normally need a cost-based optimizer to do this.

In this kind of context, the assumptions behind your question really don't apply.